# read data from external SQL database

Tags: development, 2016, external-data

What's the best approach for reading data from external SQL database?

- build web services and call it in web part
- using ado.net and read data directly in web part
- using external list and read data from external list in web part.

**I have a table with 1000000 records in SQL database**

Comment: How will the data be displayed? All records with paging? One at a time?

Comment: Doesn't matter, the main concern is the performance

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, we can use Business Connectivity Services (BCS) to achieve it.

1.Using SharePoint Designer create BCS External Content Type.

2.Using SharePoint Designer create Add/Edit/Delete operations metadata.

3.Using SharePoint Designer create Lists & Form.

4.Using Central Administration set Permissions for external Content Type.

References:

[BCS - External Database and Add/Edit/Delete Operations](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/bcs-external-database-and-addeditdelete-operations/)

[Business Connectivity Services in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/business-connectivity-services-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Thank you, I asked to select the best option , please read my question again,

Comment: I suggest you use BCS to access date from external database.

Comment: Is bcs can Handel million records?